# PHP - TCPDF Error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf, php-8.2

I have a problem with last version of TCPDF for PHP (version 8.3).

Executing this code and using TCPDF library:

```
        require_once("/var/www/shop/tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
        function CheckPageBreak($fpdf,$h) {
            //If the height h would cause an overflow, add a new page immediately
            if($fpdf->GetY()+$h>$fpdf->PageBreakTrigger()) {$fpdf->AddPage($fpdf->CurOrientation());}
        }
        
        class PDF extends TCPDF {
            function Footer() {
                if($this->PageNo()>1) {
                    $this->SetY(-10);
                    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
                    $pag=($this->PageNo())-1;
                    $this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina '.$pag,0,0,'C');
                }
            }
            function Header() {
                if($this->PageNo()>1) {
                    global $header, $w, $fontfamily;
                    $this->SetFillColor(255,255,204);
                    $this->SetDrawColor(181,11,18);
                    $this->SetTextColor(181,11,18);
                    $this->SetFont($fontfamily,'B',10);
                    $this->Ln();
                }
            }
        }

        $fontfamily = 'Arial';
        $header = array('COD.','PRODOTTO'); 

        $w = array(17,75,28,31,15,30,5); //larghezza colonne
        $altezza = 5; //altezza di una riga articolo
        $pdf = new PDF();
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,10);
        $pdf->SetMargins(5,5,5);

        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont($fontfamily,'',50);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,204);
        $pdf->SetDrawColor(181,11,18);
        $pdf->SetTextColor(181,11,18);
        $pdf->Rect(5,5,array_sum($w),282,'DF');
        $pdf->Ln(118);

        $pdf->AddPage();
        $cat_prec = "";

        foreach($item as $pro):
            $codice=         trim(mb_convert_encoding($pro["codice"], 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'));
            $descrizione=    trim($pro["prodotto"], 'ISO-8859-1');
            $nomecategoria2= trim(mb_convert_encoding($pro["nomecategoria2"], 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'));
            $pdf->SetFont($fontfamily,'',8);

            $righe = max($hdesc, $hconf, $hpeso);
            if($righe>1) {$altezza = 4;}
            else {$altezza = 5;}
            $hr = $altezza*$righe;

            if($nomecategoria2!=$cat_prec) {
                $pdf->SetFont($fontfamily,'B',10);
                $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
                $pdf->SetDrawColor(200,200,200);
                $pdf->Ln(2);
                CheckPageBreak($pdf,5+$hr);
                $pdf->Cell(array_sum($w),5,strtoupper($nomecategoria2),0,0,'L');
                $x=$pdf->GetX();
                $pdf->Ln();
                $pdf->Line($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY(),$x,$pdf->GetY());
            }
                
            CheckPageBreak($pdf,$hr);

            $pdf->SetFont($fontfamily,'B',9);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(181,11,18);
            $pdf->SetDrawColor(200,200,200);
            $pdf->Cell($w[0], $hr, $codice, 0, 0, 'L');

            $pdf->SetFont($fontfamily,'',8);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(51,51,51);
            $x=$pdf->GetX();
            $x1=$pdf->GetX();
            $y=$pdf->GetY();

            $pdf->SetX($x);
            if($hdesc>1) {$pdf->MultiCell($w[1]-$s, $altezza, $descrizione, 0, 'L');}
            else $pdf->MultiCell($w[1]-$s, $hr, $descrizione, 0, 'L');

            $pdf->SetXY($x1+$w[1],$y);
            
            $cat_prec = $nomecategoria2;
            
        endforeach;
        
        $pdf->Output("/var/www/shop/download/listino_prodotti.pdf");
        ?><script>document.getElementById('link').href='../download/listino_prodotti.pdf'; document.getElementById('link').style.display='block';</script><?php
    }
```

When i click on button that runs this script, TCPDF returns this error:

> TCPDF Error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I don't understand where is the problem, I don't use `echo` or `print_r`, how can I solve?

Comment: This is a somewhat similar problem to the _"headers already sent"_ problem. Just replace _"headers"_ by _"some data"_ and read the answers to: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957).

Comment: Look at the source of the HTML page and you should see something before the error message (it may be just a space).

Comment: Not only do you appear to have some output before the PDF output already - you are also trying to send non-PDF data _after_ the PDF, that `<script>document.getElementById('link').href=...` - which also makes no sense; you can not respond to _one_ HTTP request, with multiple types of content. _At best_ the program you use to display the PDF will ignore this extra data at the end, but it might also throw an error. And that JS code will of course never be executed.

Comment: I suggest to first activate the display error option in PHP. In fact, under PHP8.3 there is a change when you try to use a float as an int (Implicit conversion from float to int). And this happened in TCPDF.